# Selecting more than 1 text box to check if it is empty

Tags: c#, if-statement, textbox

So I made a small application. There is 6 sections of text boxes, 3 in each section.

```
string location;

Random lc = new Random();

byte i5 = (byte)lc.Next(3);
switch (i5)
{
    case 0:
        location = l1.Text;
        break;
    case 1:
        location = l2.Text;
        break;
    case 2:
        location = l3.Text;
        break;
}
```

I am wondering how to make a check to see if each box has a word in it - if even 'one' box is empty, then I don't want it to execute. If all three are filled in, then it can continue executing.

Answer (score 3):

I would do this

```
if(this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().All(t => string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Text) == false))
{
  //carry out logic
}
```

"this.Controls" refers to the parent control of the textboxes

Comment: This is more robust if you add even more textboxes as there is no need to add more if statements...

Answer (score 2):

Seems simple enough...

```
if String.IsNullOrEmpty(l1.Text) return;
if String.IsNullOrEmpty(l2.Text) return;
if String.IsNullOrEmpty(l3.Text) return;
if ....
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond. I'm aware of that method, however my code above, was only just 1 section. I mentioned I had six of those. Is there an easier way to do it, so I won't have to write out 18 of those checks?